# Query More Than 2 Tables with 1 Key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have three tables.

**1)** Product_Table

```
Product_ID
Product_Name
```

**2)** Warehouse1_Table

```
Product_ID
Inventory1
```

**3)** Warehouse2_Table

```
Product_ID
Inventory2
```

**Product ID may not exist in Warehouse1_Table or Warehouse2_Table or both**.

**I'm trying to figure out a single query which gives us something like this:**

```
Product_ID, Product_Name, TotalStock
```

TotalStock is Inventory1 + Inventory2 if the Product_ID is in both tables. 
TotalStock is Inventory1 if Product_ID is in Warehouse1_Table 
TotalStock is Inventory2 if Product_ID is in Warehouse2_Table 
TotalStock is 0 if Product_ID not in any of the Warehouse tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a LEFT JOIN, that's a join that doesn't break your query if your cross-table doesn't produce a match. And then sum up the inventories, like so:

```
SELECT p.Product_ID, p.Product_Name,
(IFNULL(w1.Inventory1, 0) + ISNULL(w2.Inventory2, 0)) AS TotalStock
FROM `Product_Table` AS p
LEFT JOIN `Warehouse1_Table` AS w1 ON (
    p.Product_ID = w1.Product_ID
) LEFT JOIN `Warehouse2_Table` AS w2 ON (
    p.Product_ID = w2.Product_ID
);
```

Then your resultset should contain the 'TotalStock' field with either the combined stock or the stock that either one of the warehouses returned.

Comment: `NULL + 3 = NULL` => you need `IFNULL(w1.Inventory1, 0) + ISNULL(w2.Inventory2, 0)`

Comment: This assumes that product_id is unique within each warehouse table (which is implied by the OP, but not stated.)  +1

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work. I've added some sample data to illustrate what I'm getting at:

```
 create table Product_table
(Product_ID int unsigned primary key,Product_Name varchar(50) not null,
UNIQUE KEY `Product_TableUIdx1` (Product_Name));

create table Warehouse1_Table
(Product_ID int unsigned not null,Inventory1 int,
UNIQUE KEY `Warehouse1_Table_UIdx1` (Product_Id));

create table Warehouse2_Table
(Product_ID int unsigned,Inventory2 int,
UNIQUE KEY `Warehouse2_Table_UIdx1` (Product_Id));

insert into Product_table values (1,"Banana");
insert into Product_table values (2,"Apple");
insert into Product_table values (3,"Pear");
insert into Product_table values (4,"Orange");

insert into Warehouse1_Table values (1,2);

insert into Warehouse2_Table values (3,10);
insert into Warehouse2_Table values (4,5);
insert into Warehouse2_Table values (1,3);

select pt.Product_ID,pt.Product_Name,
ifnull(wt1.Inventory1,0)+ifnull(wt2.Inventory2,0) as StockTotal
from Product_table pt
left outer join Warehouse1_Table wt1 on wt1.Product_ID = pt.Product_ID
left outer join Warehouse2_Table wt2 on wt2.Product_ID = pt.Product_ID;
```

Thanks to the eagle eyes of Dems for pointing out that it is important to avoid duplication arising from multiple rows for the same Product_ID in either Warehouse1_Table or Warehouse1_Table. If adding unique keys as in the above DDL is not possible then you could address that using a (somewhat uglier) query like this:

```
select pt.Product_ID,pt.Product_Name,
ifnull(wt1.Inventory1Total,0)+ifnull(wt2.Inventory2Total,0) as StockTotal
from Product_table pt
left outer join (select w1.Product_ID,sum(w1.Inventory1) as Inventory1Total
from Warehouse1_Table w1 group by w1.Product_ID) as wt1 on wt1.Product_ID = pt.Product_ID
left outer join (select w2.Product_ID,sum(w2.Inventory2) as Inventory2Total
from Warehouse2_Table w2 group by w2.Product_ID) as wt2 on wt2.Product_ID = pt.Product_ID;
```

Comment: Uses IFNULL to deal with case that no records exist in one of other table.  And combines them into a single field.  However...  You're using a SUM(), so do you anticipate multiple entries if the same product ID in the warehouse tables?  If so, LEFT JOINing the in this way will cause duplication.  (2 records in w1, 3 records in w2 => 3 records after joining)

Comment: @Dems - good point. I guess a better would be to remove the sum and enforce a unique constraint on the Product_ID column on both the `Warehouse1_Table` and `Warehouse2_Table`. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Product_ID,
       Product_Name,
       SUM(w1.Inventory1) as sum1,
       SUM(w2.Inventroy2) as sum2           

FROM Product_Table p
LEFT JOIN Warehouse1_Table w1 ON p.Product_ID = w1.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN Warehouse2_Table w2 ON p.Product_ID = w2.Product_ID
GROUP BY p.Product_ID
```

I haven't tested it but that's the idea.

Comment: Doesn't deal with there being no record in the warehouse table  (Gives NULL, need 0).  Doesn't combine the results into a single total column.  Use of SUM indicates a belief that product_id is not unique in the warehouse tables, but if that is true the LEFT JOINs will create duplication (2 records in w1, 3 records in w2 => 6 records after the left join.)

Comment: Great comment. However I can't see your answer so we can all learn something.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Product_ID, Product_Name, 
       Inventory1 + Inventory2 AS TotalStock
  FROM Product_Table 
       NATURAL JOIN Warehouse1_Table
       NATURAL JOIN Warehouse2_Table
UNION
SELECT Product_ID, Product_Name, 
       Inventory1 AS TotalStock
  FROM Product_Table 
       NATURAL JOIN Warehouse1_Table
 WHERE Product_ID NOT IN (
                          SELECT Product_ID 
                            FROM Warehouse2_Table
                         )
UNION
SELECT Product_ID, Product_Name, 
       Inventory2 AS TotalStock
  FROM Product_Table 
       NATURAL JOIN Warehouse2_Table
 WHERE Product_ID NOT IN (
                          SELECT Product_ID 
                            FROM Warehouse1_Table
                         )
UNION
SELECT Product_ID, Product_Name, 
       0 AS TotalStock
  FROM Product_Table 
 WHERE Product_ID NOT IN (
                          SELECT Product_ID 
                            FROM Warehouse1_Table
                         )
       AND Product_ID NOT IN (
                              SELECT Product_ID 
                                FROM Warehouse2_Table
                             );
```